# Typewriter animation who select and delete

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a Typewriter animation who write simple text but then it should `select` and `delete` a small part of the text he just created.

Here's a gif of what I exactly want found on http://mattfarley.ca.

[image: Example]

---

I've already tried to do some simple CSS [typewriter](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_typewriter.asp)

```css
/* Google Fonts */

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anonymous+Pro);

/* Global */

html {
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  height: calc(100vh - 8em);
  padding: 4em;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;
  background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
}

.line-1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  width: 24em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  font-size: 180%;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/* Animation */

.anim-typewriter {
  animation: typewriter 4s steps(44) 1s 1 normal both, blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(44) infinite normal;
}

@keyframes typewriter {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 24em;
  }
}

@keyframes blinkTextCursor {
  from {
    border-right-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  }
  to {
    border-right-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="line-1 anim-typewriter">Animation typewriter style using css steps()</p>
```

---

Answer or links are highly appreciated edit if I missed something.

Comment: I think they followed this tutorial: https://codyhouse.co/gem/css-animated-headlines or source code on Github https://github.com/CodyHouse/animated-headline

Comment: It's not a pure css solution, but typewriter js will do what you want it to do.

Comment: Try this, i am not sure what you exactly need, i think it's helps. https://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Simulating-Typing-Deleting-Selecting-Text-With-jQuery-typewrite.html

Comment: Follow this **tutorial**: *They are coded based on this* https://codyhouse.co/gem/css-animated-headlines **Github:** https://github.com/CodyHouse/animated-headline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@l2aelba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50019529/typewriter-animation-who-select-and-delete#comment87081639_50019529) said:

> **Follow this tutorial**: *They are coded based on this* [codyhouse.co/gem/css-animated-headlines](https://codyhouse.co/gem/css-animated-headlines)

---

*I'm just creating a correct answer so the question can be completed.*

---

## Implement a Typewriting animation

[From this GitHub repo.](https://github.com/CodyHouse/animated-headline/tree/d95148f30557c5ac871f7f55091379b0b811cfad)

1. ### Add Styles

   1.1 Add Primary style ([style.css](https://github.com/CodyHouse/animated-headline/blob/master/css/style.css))

   1.2 Add the correct section style (in my case: [xtype](https://github.com/CodyHouse/animated-headline/blob/d95148f30557c5ac871f7f55091379b0b811cfad/css/style.css#L288))

   1.3 (*Optionnal*) Add SCSS style ([style.scss](https://github.com/CodyHouse/animated-headline/blob/d95148f30557c5ac871f7f55091379b0b811cfad/scss/style.scss)) with [partials](https://github.com/CodyHouse/animated-headline/tree/d95148f30557c5ac871f7f55091379b0b811cfad/partials) (pay attention on location folder.)

---

2. ### Add JavaScript

   2.1 Add [main.js](https://github.com/CodyHouse/animated-headline/blob/d95148f30557c5ac871f7f55091379b0b811cfad/js/main.js) in your main.js file.

   2.2 Add [JQuery](https://jquery.com), I've used the [jquery-2.1.1](https://github.com/CodyHouse/animated-headline/blob/d95148f30557c5ac871f7f55091379b0b811cfad/js/jquery-2.1.1.js) version.
3. ### Add HTML

   3.1 Use your appropriate section [in all those choices](https://github.com/CodyHouse/animated-headline/blob/d95148f30557c5ac871f7f55091379b0b811cfad/index.html).

   3.2 In my case it was: [type](https://github.com/CodyHouse/animated-headline/blob/d95148f30557c5ac871f7f55091379b0b811cfad/index.html#L30).

## Result

Thanks everyone!

[image: Result]